# Unable to run PowerShell from C#: The 'Get-WindowsOptionalFeature' command was found in the module 'Dism', but the module could not be loaded

Tags: c#, powershell

I tried to execute the following PowerShell command from my c# application.

```
$check = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
if ($check.Installed -eq 'False') {
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
}
```

But when I run this, the PowerShell raises the following exception:

> The 'Get-WindowsOptionalFeature' command was found in the module 'Dism', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module Dism'

However, when I run the same script from the PowerShell window, it works just fine. What is the root of my problem? My operating system is Windows 10.

PowerShell version: 5 - 1 - 14393 - 953

C# Code:

```
const string psScript = @"$check = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
if ($check.Installed -eq 'False') {
    Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45
}";

using (var PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript(psScript);
    var PSOutput = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

    if (PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
    {                       
        foreach (var err in PowerShellInstance.Streams.Error)
            logger.LogError(err.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var outputItem in PSOutput)
    {            
        if (outputItem != null)
            logger.LogInfo(outputItem.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including 'Import-Module Dism' inside your script, like this:

```
const string psScript = @"Import-Module Dism; $check = Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45 if ($check.Installed -eq 'False') { Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45 };";
```

Comment: Although this might be the case, it didn't work on the machine that raised that issue. It works fine on my machine, but we have a Windows 10 machine that fails that script. What I'm guessing is a module missing on my Windows machine. Or a broken module somewhere. But why it works fine on the PowerShell command line application but shows this error from C#?

Comment: Yes, is posible that you don't have the modules installed. Try installing https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=40855 in your win10 machine.